# How to know perfect filesystem parameters for flash drive format

Tags: linux, btrfs, flash-memory

I have a flash drive and using btrfs on it with default parameters. And now I'm going to slightly improve read/write speed. I see that "play the game" with page and sector size can helps me. But didn't know physical parameters of flash drive. How can I get this parameters? I have Sandisk cruze glide 128G.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be using a USB 2.0 flash drive. In this form factor, it is not possible to obtain flash parameters by querying the device since USB bridges do not have support for sending query commands.

More technical details:

http://sg.danny.cz/sg/sdparm.html

The flash bench tool can be used to guess device parameters by observing it's performance characteristics but in my experience, it is difficult to draw definitive conclusions from it,

https://github.com/bradfa/flashbench